# I want to print only the last log between'=====' and'====='

Tags: awk, sed

Below is status log of linux server.

I only want to print the last log between'=====' and'====='.

-- Below is that log.

```
# cat /var/log/server-status/status.log
~~ snip ~~
==============================================
2020-08-13_23:49:21_KST UnixTime=1597330161
1 Min Average Load::2.45(CPUS:2)
----------------------------------------------
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     31394 99.4  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   21:41 127:11 stress -c 2
root     31395 99.3  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   21:41 127:08 stress -c 2
root      2838  0.2  0.0 157500  2344 pts/0    S+   Aug06  25:55 watch -d -n1 uptime
rpc        904  0.0  0.0  69280  1004 ?        Ss   Aug06   0:00 /sbin/rpcbind -w
root       935  0.0  0.2 550668 11180 ?        Ssl  Aug06   0:07 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
----------------------------------------------
==============================================

==============================================
2020-08-13_23:51:38_KST UnixTime=1597330298
MEM USAGE::41.20(ThreadHold:41)
----------------------------------------------
==============================================

==============================================
2020-08-13_23:52:41_KST UnixTime=1597330361
----------------------------------------------
MEM USAGE::41.21(ThreadHold:41)
----------------------------------------------
==============================================

==============================================
2020-08-13_23:53:03_KST UnixTime=1597330383
----------------------------------------------
1 Min Average Load::2.22(CPUS:2)
----------------------------------------------
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     31394 99.4  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   21:41 130:52 stress -c 2
root     31395 99.3  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   21:41 130:49 stress -c 2
root      2838  0.2  0.0 157500  2344 pts/0    S+   Aug06  25:56 watch -d -n1 uptime
rpc        904  0.0  0.0  69280  1004 ?        Ss   Aug06   0:00 /sbin/rpcbind -w
root       935  0.0  0.2 550668 11180 ?        Ssl  Aug06   0:07 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
----------------------------------------------
MEM USAGE::41.18(ThreadHold:41)
----------------------------------------------
==============================================
```

-- I used the method below.
However, this result is not accurate.

```
# tail -n 20 /var/log/server-status/status.log | sed -n -e '/UnixTime/,/==/ p'
2020-08-14_00:24:49_KST UnixTime=1597332289
----------------------------------------------
1 Min Average Load::2.24 (CPUS:2)
----------------------------------------------
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     31395 99.4  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   Aug13 162:25 stress -c 2
root     31394 99.4  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   Aug13 162:27 stress -c 2
root      2838  0.2  0.0 157500  2344 pts/0    S+   Aug06  26:00 watch -d -n1 uptime
root      9713  0.1  0.1 161536  6088 ?        Ss   00:24   0:00 sshd: root@pts/6
rpc        904  0.0  0.0  69280  1004 ?        Ss   Aug06   0:00 /sbin/rpcbind -w
----------------------------------------------
==============================================
```

This is because sometimes the log below may be the last.

```
==============================================
2020-08-13_23:51:38_KST UnixTime=1597330298
MEM USAGE::41.20(ThreadHold:41)
----------------------------------------------
==============================================
```

--> That is, because the line can be variable.

```
# tail -n 20 /var/log/server-status/status.log | sed -n -e '/UnixTime/,/==/ p'
2020-08-13_23:51:38_KST UnixTime=1597330298
MEM USAGE::41.20(ThreadHold:41)
----------------------------------------------
==============================================
2020-08-13_23:52:58_KST UnixTime=1597330298
MEM USAGE::41.20(ThreadHold:41)
----------------------------------------------
==============================================
```

--> This is not the result I want.

How can I print properly only the last log between'=====' and'====='?

Thanks

Comment: You could call Perl in bash that only keeps the last data that was before '====='.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact expected output as it's not clear if `between` means including or excluding the `===` lines.

Answer (score 4):

GNU sed will do the trick:

```
sed -n '/UnixTime/h;//!H;$!d;x;//p' /var/log/server-status/status.log
```

**Background:** This will replace anything in the hold space by the line containing "UnixTime" (aka last occurrence), then will append all following lines to the hold space. Once it's reached the bottom it will swap the pattern space for the hold space and then print out the result (as long as there is a match).

Depending on the content, you could pipe the content from cat as well, but I don't believe this will be necessary.

For **scenario #1** will give:

```
2020-08-13_23:53:03_KST UnixTime=1597330383
----------------------------------------------
1 Min Average Load::2.22(CPUS:2)
----------------------------------------------
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     31394 99.4  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   21:41 130:52 stress -c 2
root     31395 99.3  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   21:41 130:49 stress -c 2
root      2838  0.2  0.0 157500  2344 pts/0    S+   Aug06  25:56 watch -d -n1 uptime
rpc        904  0.0  0.0  69280  1004 ?        Ss   Aug06   0:00 /sbin/rpcbind -w
root       935  0.0  0.2 550668 11180 ?        Ssl  Aug06   0:07 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
----------------------------------------------
MEM USAGE::41.18(ThreadHold:41)
----------------------------------------------
==============================================
```

For **scenario #2** will give:

```
2020-08-13_23:51:38_KST UnixTime=1597330298
MEM USAGE::41.20(ThreadHold:41)
----------------------------------------------
==============================================
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Using `tac` + `awk` combination here. Reading Input_file in reverse do that we need not to read whole Input_file. Just read last stanza from 2nd last occurrence of = to last occurrence of =(which becomes first occurrence to second occurrence reading because tac reads Input_file reverse). So once awk processes it, it will be in reverse format hence using again one more tac to print lines in actual format. Written on mobile so yet to test it should work but.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk '
/^=/{
  if(++count==1){ found=1 }
  if(count>1)   { exit    }
}
found' | 
tac
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ tac file | awk '/^=/{c++} c; c==2{exit}' | tac
==============================================
2020-08-13_23:53:03_KST UnixTime=1597330383
----------------------------------------------
1 Min Average Load::2.22(CPUS:2)
----------------------------------------------
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     31394 99.4  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   21:41 130:52 stress -c 2
root     31395 99.3  0.0   7312    96 pts/4    R+   21:41 130:49 stress -c 2
root      2838  0.2  0.0 157500  2344 pts/0    S+   Aug06  25:56 watch -d -n1 uptime
rpc        904  0.0  0.0  69280  1004 ?        Ss   Aug06   0:00 /sbin/rpcbind -w
root       935  0.0  0.2 550668 11180 ?        Ssl  Aug06   0:07 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
----------------------------------------------
MEM USAGE::41.18(ThreadHold:41)
----------------------------------------------
==============================================
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed` (relying on `===` on the last line and removing that line):

```
sed -rz 's/.*===\n(.+)\n==*/\1/' file
```

Without deleting the last line with `====` the answer is easier:

```
sed -rz 's/.*===\n(.+)/\1/' file
```